# .htaccess never throwing error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to PHP and especially Apache but I am familiar with NodeJS. I am trying to use the Slim Micro Framework with PHP/Apache and I am having problems due to my .htaccess because it never seems to give any errors, even with `asdfasfsf` at the top of my .htaccess file.

I need this to run:

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

So that my server will return trigger my http `/home` route made with Slim, instead of searching for a `/home` directory, but it has been really hard to debug when Apache doesn't throw any errors.

From my research, I believe I have to do something in the `etc` folder, but I just installed Apache2_4 without any XAMP or WAMP, so I don't have this folder yet. I would appreciate any tips on using middleware to serve static .css and .js files as well if that's a thing.

routes.php

```
<?php

$server->get('/home', function ($request, $response) {
    return 'Home';
});
```

Comment: I don't think `!-f` would trigger at all since `/home` is a directory so `!-d` would probably work instead.

Comment: Change `AllowOverride` in your apache config to `All` https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: Do i need to create a directory in there also?

Comment: `<Directory>` i mean?